# Stabilizer over group action of G on itself by left multiplication

Tags: group-theory

Would it be correct to say that the stabilizer in this case is the trivial group $\{1\}$ under multiplication? Can there possibly be other elements in this group?

Comment: Start with what it means for an element to be in the stabilizer, and then use right-cancellation. What do you get?

Comment: For $g_i$ acting on $g_j$, $g_i \cdot g_j = g_j$ - this is the stabilizer, if I'm correct.

Comment: A stabilizer is a set of elements that satisfy a certain property - when you say "this" is the stabilizer, I am not sure if you understand the definition.

Comment: A stabilizer of an element $a \in A$ which is acted upon by group $G$ is a set of elements in $G$ that satisfy the property that $g \cdot a = a$ for all $a \in A$.

Comment: So it appears that the group is $\{e\}$, where $e$ is the identity element of the group.